# do db connections get closed Immediately as soon as the page is finished processing?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

In a php script, is it **guaranteed** that once the script/page ends, an opened database connection is closed **without any furthur delay** ? *(keywords in bold)*

Or is it true that the connection will hang around open for like a few seconds (or even milliseconds) before closing?

By *without any furthur delay*, i meant that it would be just as fast as if we were to compare it with explicitly closing the database connections at the **last line** of the php script of that page.

Comment: It takes time for the connection to close. milliseconds, hard for me to say. nanoseconds, I can guarantee it :P There will always be some delay though, in everything.

Comment: Define '_without further delay_': it might take some time before the cleanup code is reached which closes the connection, although this is not done deliberately. This might be a few milliseconds with a busy server, so does that count as 'without further delay' as this delay is not deliberate?

Comment: Read the documentation of the components you're using, this is different depending on configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the method of connecting to the db, you could always use a close command.  That way, you could be sure of when the connection is closed, and know that it is closed when the script is done.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you configure mysql. There is an option to keep the connection for the whole session (persistent connection). Normally this should be avoided and I can't think of any usecase now.

Comment: Just read http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php. TLDR: when PHP is run as module for web server connection structures/sockets can be reused by new requests, no overhead in connecting to database (for example if your script only makes a fast request to database and don't use it anymore your connection creation overhead can be significant(I got close to 30% of all mysql usage once)).